# anaconda - ipynb file not opening after been saved on windows pc

Tags: windows, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

actually a novice here but recently installed the anaconda distribution and lunched the jupyter notebook. tried running few operations and saved on desktop, after sometimes, I tried clicking on the file saved on desktop but it isn't opening. my question is-> is there a particular type of file to save you IPYNB. operation on with windows? or rather save IPYNB file on windows system.

Comment: Start up Jupyter and then from in Jupyter try opening your file. Anaconda itself doesn't handle opening the notebook, and so you cannot just click on it to open the file the way you would with a Microsoft Word file. For example, within Anaconda, you can select JupyterLab as a way to open a notebook or you can select the classic Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: If you want to be able to click on the `.ipynb` files, see how to set it up for when using Anaconda [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57064782/8508004).